# C# - Copy pasting of image into outlook set it as twice attachment files

Tags: c#, outlook, email-attachments

I am currently working on an addin project for outlook in visual studio 2013.
When I copy paste an image into outlook and send mail through it,it considers the same image twice in the html attachment.How can I allow to show only one image in the attachment? Or how can remove the second  attachment?

Copy Pasted one Image to outlook:

[image]

Outlool.MailItem.Attachments look like:

[image]

Got two Attachments when I pasted one Image.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: How is this related to *programming*? And why should any addin treat *two* pastes as *one*? Just don't paste twice. Are you using copy/pasting instead of interop to automate Outlook perhaps?

Comment: The issue is that I have a word template which contains the image in it.I have to programmatically copy and paste the image from the word file and paste it into outlook body ,after that I send the mail .While sending the email ,the mail attachment shows two images instead of one .

Answer (score 0):

Instead, can you try to get a picture from the local? Just test the problem and see if there will be such a problem.
Also, I found a way to add attachments from locally saved files to the mail and display them in HTML to the body. For your reference:

newMail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

Outlook.Attachment attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add(@"path.imageformat", Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, $"someTitle");

string imagecid = "whatever";

attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3613041E", imagecid);

newMail.HTMLBody = String.Format("", imageCid);